# How to reduce the number of threads used by the jvm

Tags: java, jvm

I'm running a single threaded Java app on the following java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

with the `-XX:+UseSerialGC` option enabled. Still when I start the application I see multiple threads starting when monitoring the system with `htop`. I'd like to reduce the number of processes started as much as possible since I have a use case which involves running multiple instances of this application and this will hit the roof of the maximum allowed number of process on the system that I'm running on. Are there any other jvm options other than `-XX:+UseSerialGC` that I could use to reduce the number of threads starting?

Comment: Couldn't you just run multiple instances in the same JVM e.g. by starting multiple Java threads? Depending on your application you then could even use tasks instead of threads etc.

Comment: This might help you if using multiple Java threads as Thomas suggested [A Method for Reducing Contention and Overhead in Worker Queues for Multithreaded Java Applications](https://today.java.net/article/2011/06/14/method-reducing-contention-and-overhead-worker-queues-multithreaded-java-applications)

Comment: Threads are not processes. Your question is founded on a misapprehension.

Comment: @EJP Oh really? Does Linux `clone` syscall create a process or a thread then? Does `RLIMIT_NPROC` limits the number of processes or the number of threads?

Comment: @apangin Yes really. I don't see what `clone` and friends have to do with it. Linux misdescribes threads as processes here and there, but that doesn't mean that JVM threads *are* processes.

Comment: @EJP Linux doesn't misdescribe threads because threads *are* lightweight processes in Linux. JVM threads are mapped to OS threads and that's the problem. When `RLIMIT_NPROC` is set, e.g. `ulimit -u 100`, a user is able to start 100 processes or 50 2-threaded processes or only 10 processes each with 10 threads. So OP's question really makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apart from `-XX:+UseSerialGC` which disables Parallel or Concurrent GC, there are the following options to reduce the number of JVM threads:

- `-XX:CICompilerCount=1` leaves only one JIT compiler thread.
- `-XX:+ReduceSignalUsage` disables Signal Dispatcher thread. E.g. JVM will not handle SIGQUIT to dump threads.
- `-XX:+DisableAttachMechanism` prevents AttachListener thread from starting.

In theory it is possible to disable even more threads (e.g. Service Thread and VM Periodic Task Thread) but this would require patching JVM.