# Does OpenJDK Hotspot JVM utilise ergonomics to determine number of housekeeping threads (respect docker pids limits)

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, jvm, jvm-arguments

I may be framing the title of this question entirely incorrectly, so perhaps it's better to start from observed behaviour.

I've set a PIDs limit using docker-compose of 120 PIDS for a java based image. To be precise `adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.2.9-alpine-slim`

The 120 was a little arbitrary in that all i did was use `docker stats` to look at 20 running images and noting the they at the time all had PID counts of <100 and I gave 20 more as headroom.

I have since observed some behaviour where errors like this occur:

> caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached

and `docker stats` shows me memory usage of around 80% e.g:

> 301.8MiB / 376MiB 80.26% mem used

but crucially 120 pids.

I'm now wondering a few things:

1. did i just set 120 too low and if so, what's reasonable - might depend a lot on my specific use case like thread pool sizes, concurrent requests and GC activity etc. But if this is the case, what's the best way to measure - perhaps measure PIDS activity over a week or two and set a level a little higher than max.
2. Is the JVM even aware of the PIDS limit that's currently applied, can VM ergonomics even detect this limit and know whether the VM is able to create more threads or are there flags which would be able to tell it. If it even *can* do that, would that fundamentally change anything, e.g. VM would be more conservative about number of threads it tries to start to do things like GC or JIT or internal house keeping?

Comment: 1. Why limit PIDs at all? Depending on the application, it may create hundreds or even thousands threads. 2. JVM itself creates fixed number of threads. Again, it's up to the application to spawn new threads, and JVM cannot prevent the application from doing this. So, NO - JVM does not take PIDs limit into account.

Comment: As for why, to provide better isolation to limit fall out of a misbehaving application; e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb#Java I wasn't expecting the JVM to take action to prevent application threads from being created. I was more wondering whether there are VM ergonomics in play like those which can happen for number of CPU detection of available memory when the JVM allocates things like GC threads and adaptive heap sizing - e.g. if the JVM were aware of some limit to number of threads it can spawn my thinking was that *perhaps* it might be less aggressive in doing so.

Comment: If JVM could work with less threads with the same performance, why would it create more threads in the first place? You [can reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25706865/3448419) the number of GC, Compiler and a few other threads manually, but this will likely affect performance or serviceability. JVM does not do this automatically.

Comment: I take your point and agree. The answer is becoming more clear and your knowledge about the internals of the JVM is very useful. I didn't state that I expected or wanted the same performance with fewer threads. My main goal was to improve isolation in the event that one container starts to consume "too much resource" which could negatively impact other supposedly isolated containers rather than maintaining the same level of throughput for e.g. Anyway, it seems the answer is now clear, no the JVM has not knowledge of the PID limit and even if it did it doesn't do anything adaptive, thanks.